# PT Cruiser will not start

Tags: starting, troubleshooting, chrysler

The battery is fully charged.  The lights come on and there isn't a clicking noise.  I had the ignition switch replaced and it still will not start

Answer (score 4):

Offhand, sounds like something is bad in the system for delivering power to the starter motor. It could be a blown fuse, damage to the wiring, or a bad starter relay/solenoid. If you don't hear *any* click when you try to start, it's probably not the starter motor itself that's bad.